# Is the phrase "Thank you for your effort" is the best way to praise someone for the help he giving me?

Tags: phrase-requests, vocabulary

Let's say that I'm doing my daily labor, and it's a pretty hard work in general.
And someone offer to help me, without I that asked for it, and surprisingly that person invested in that job a lot more than I could imagine.
Could it be possible that my only option to gratitude him is to say something like:
`Thank you for your effort`?

What I really want to know, if there is any better way to rephrase the word "effort" to something more suitable that can describe how much I appreciate what he had done.

Comment: You should never follow the word "the" with the word "your". Choose one.

Comment: @ParthianShot oops, that was unintentionally typo. sorry about that.

Comment: You could say, "Thanks - I couldn't have done it without you."  (It's a common expression.)

Comment: @Oldbag The thing is, I **could** do it without him. But still, I wanted him to know that is wasn't taken for granted.

Comment: The generic would be "Thank you for your assistance."  But if an extraordinary amount of effort was expended by the other party you should go beyond using a stock phrase and do your best in your own words to express your gratitude.  Your own words are appreciated more than a canned response, no matter how fancy.

Comment: @HashiramaSenju - It's not about your ability to do the job yourself - it's about being gracious.

Comment: You could say something like "I really appreciate your help" or "Thanks for all your work."

Answer (score 3):

Truly, the only thing wrong with your statement is its connotation in some circumstances, or in some geographic areas. In situations, the sentence may be inferred as, "Thank you for your effort, (even though you didn't help all that much).

Hot Licks is spot on (see comments). You don't have to exaggerate (as in when you could have handled it by yourself). Say something that reflects your true appreciation:

"Thank you for your contribution to this project. Your investment in time and energy was far beyond what I could/would have asked for." (in your words, of course).